# Dropzone - Can't set custom Dropzone.js options

Tags: javascript, laravel, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am trying to use [Dropzone.js](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#) on my Laravel website.

This is my setup:

`index.blade.php`:

```
<form action="/documents" method="POST" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
</form>
```

And in my `app.js` file, I have below code:

```
window.Dropzone = require('dropzone');

(function () {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        maxFilesize: 1, // MB
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*,application/pdf',
        parallelUploads: 8,
        addRemoveLinks: false,
        createImageThumbnails: false,
        autoProcessQueue: true,
        previewTemplate: document.getElementById('dropzone-preview-template').innerHTML,

        accept: function (file, done) {
            console.log(file.name)
        },

    };
});
```

The actual Dropzone element is appearing on the page, and I can use it to upload files. However, my `Dropzone.options` are not being respected.

For example, I can upload files larger than 1MB, I can upload **all** file types, even though I only want to be able to upload images and PDF files.

If I move this: `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;` outside the `(function () {});`, the Dropzone element don't work at all.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have surrounded your code in a anonymous function but are not calling it, so the plugin options code is not being executed. Either remove this anonymous function, or call it, like so:

```
(function () {

})(); // call the function
```

Answer (score 1):

try it like this instead:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzone", {
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 1, // MB
  acceptedFiles: "image/*,application/pdf",
  parallelUploads: 8,
  addRemoveLinks: false,
  createImageThumbnails: false,
  autoProcessQueue: true,
  previewTemplate: document.getElementById("dropzone-preview-template")
    .innerHTML,

  accept: function(file, done) {
    console.log(file.name);
  }
});
```